# Why @Getter of Lombok propagates field annotation @NotNull?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

My question is simple and the answer could be simpler but I haven't found anything so far.

[image: Original code]

Lombok 1.18.24 (last so far) propagates annotation "@NotNull" to its generated getter method, as I checked out using a decompiler over the .class file:

[image: Generated code]

It is funny because other annotations such as @javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty, it does not propagate. It is my solution so far.

I tried to use `lombok.config` as follows (but no success):

> lombok.copyableAnnotations -= javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

and as follows (no success either):

> clear lombok.addNullAnnotations

In short, I would like Lombok **does** not propagate it. *How to avoid @Getter propagates field annotation @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull to respective getter?*

Comment: but if the field is never null, then why shouldn't the getter enforce the same? is this for educational purposes or do you have a realistic reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you want Lombok not to propagate this?

Comment: @LouisWasserman because this annotation should be automatically propagated by the IDE/compiler and users should decided if they want to see them or not, we should not have to write it explicitly everywhere in the code, otherwise it will become ulgy very fast.

Comment: Nah.  Every method should explicitly declare its nullability.

Comment: It is definitely not educational. I am Java consultant and JSF 2.3 running on JDK 17 does not work properly due to this propagation (field to Lombok created getter). I changed all annotations to @NotEmpty and it works just fine. However, I just want to understand two things: (i) why does Lombok propagate some annotations and does not others? and (ii) why does not Lombok provide us with some configuration to determine what we want to propagate or not.

Comment: This behaviour was introduced in lombok 1.18.24. The Projectlombok [may release a fix in a 1.18.26 version](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3180) - someday. Perhaps you can use the 1.18.22 version meanwhile.

Comment: Indeed Badaro. I am using NotEmpty and it worked for me better than the older one. But I am going to check if the 1.18.26 version fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @LouisWasserman In my case I wouldn't like the propagation. With upgrade lombok from 1.18.10 to 1.18.30 my code breaks because bean validation brings me duplicate constraint violations now. Once for the member variable and once for the getter. So maybe you could argue that the validator (fairly old org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl) should work better here. Haven't tried with other bean validators.

Comment: ok, HibernateValidator and maybe a lot of other libs only want to have one annotation:
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3166#issuecomment-1091090969

and Lombok changed the propagation and say it's a feature not a bug:
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3166#issuecomment-1102953740

Comment: Just found out it's fixed already. Even if the ticket comments in lombok didn't looked promising. Fixed since 1.18.26 with this commit: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/commit/1473389f397579a224d57b496f6387f3b8cbb6a9